# Can an Ethernet cable still work properly without the coating, indoors?

Tags: ethernet, cable

I need to squeeze an ethernet cable under a door (as I can't drill a wall, Powerline adapters are out of the question, and Wi-Fi has too much of a packet loss to use here), but it doesn't fit whole. If I remove the coating from a small section and pass the four pairs paralel under the door, would it cause any problems? This is an indoor environment without any more electromagnetic noise than the average household, and I have a cat5e avaliable.
Thank you.

Comment: You are likely to distort the pairs in such a way as to cause frame drops. I doubt that is would then pass the tests required for 1 Gbps. UTP cables need to use a proper cable path and be loose. I once saw a cable that was flattened to fit, much like this, and there was one application which just wouldn't work. It turned out that it was sensitive to frame drops and retransmissions, and that was 10 Mbps ethernet. Why can't you create a proper path?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are flat Ethernet cables. Maybe they'll work for you. Just google for "flat Ethernet cable".

Answer (score 4):

yes, this may cause issues.  The wires inside the insulator (what you are calling coating) is twisted to prevent any interference.

As a network engineer, I have been in situation where everything works fine with a network cable without the insulator.  But I would not recommend having it as it may cause degradation in your network bandwidth.

Comment: I've seen it work OK in a couple of cases, too, where the person who made the mod was careful about keeping the twists as close to original as possible.  But, I've seen it fail (usually in very mysterious ways) even more often.

Comment: @MAP It must be a reply!